# db.StringProperty but property is occasionally datastore_types.Text?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Are there any circumstances under which GAE datastore might change a property type from `StringProperty` to `TextProperty` (effectively ignoring the model definition)?

Consider the following situation (simplified):

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    user_input = db.StringProperty(default='', multiline=True)
```

Some entity instances of this model in my datastore have a datatype of `TextProperty` for 'user_input' (rather than simple `str`) and are therefore not indexed. I can fix this by retrieving the entity, setting `model_instance.user_input = str(model_instance.user_input)` and then putting the entity back into the datastore.

What I don't understand is how this is happening to only some entities, when there have been no changes to this model. Is it possible that the'type' of a db.model's property can be overridden from `StringProperty` to `TextProperty`?

Comment: The type the field had is stored along with the data in the property. The only way you could get TextProperty for a field is is the Model was defined as a TextProperty at some point.  Possibly two different model definitions, do you keep a date created and date modified with your model data ? That might help define when the data was created/modified.

Comment: @Tim Hoffman "The only way you could get TextProperty for a field is if the Model was defined as a TextProperty at some point.". Not true, `setattr` can bypass the model definition when a property of a different type is assigned, see my answer below.

Comment: You have completely rebound the property of the instance , see my answer below.

Comment: @Tim Hoffman - Your example only works because you don't `put` and then `get` the entity from datastore. If you add this to your example (as per my modified answer), the id's of `string_type` and `text_type` will be unique .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there IS a way the type of a property from the model's definition can be bypassed (and this was our case)! The following self contained example runs in the interactive console and demonstrates the bug. Essentially, `setattr` bypasses the property's type if you assign an existing property of a different type:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
class TestModel(db.Model):
    string_type = db.StringProperty(default='', multiline=True)
    text_type = db.TextProperty()

some_instance = TestModel()
some_instance.text_type = 'foobar'
setattr(some_instance, 'string_type', some_instance.text_type)
some_instance.put()

retrieved_instance = db.get(some_instance.key())

print id(retrieved_instance.string_type) #10166414447674124776
print id(retrieved_instance.text_type) #10166414447721032360

print type(retrieved_instance.string_type) #OOPS: string_type is now Text type!
```

Answer (score 1):

At least in `ndb` there is a special code path for StringProperties containing  Unicode  **if the property is not indexed**. In this case it is changed into a Text Property:
The relevant snippet is:

```
if isinstance(value, str):
  v.set_stringvalue(value)
elif isinstance(value, unicode):
  v.set_stringvalue(value.encode('utf8'))
  if not self._indexed:
    p.set_meaning(entity_pb.Property.TEXT)
```

I'm unable to observe this on the Python side (see [db.StringProperty but property is occasionally datastore_types.Text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254344/db-stringproperty-but-property-is-occasionally-datastore-types-text#)) but I see it in the datastore and it caused headaches when loading the Datastore into BigQuery.

So use only:

- StringProperty(indexed=True)
- TextProperty()

Avoid `StringProperty(indexed=False)` If you might write mixed `unicode` and `str` values to the property - as it tends to happen with external data.

Answer (score 0):

There's a length limit on `StringProperty` of 500 characters. I don't know for sure, but maybe the datastore will convert a `StringProperty` to a `TextProperty` if it goes over the limit.

Having said that, I doubt GAE would just change an indexed property to a non-indexed one implicitly. But it's all I can think of.

Comment: Good suggestion, so I'm running a couple of tests - but it seems unlikely. This is affecting several hundred entities in a set of a few thousand, and the 'user_input' is a country drop down so I don't see how we would have that many 500+ character countries! (that's a lot of hackers).

Comment: In my experience, while the StringProperty over 500 characters, it will raise an BadValueError.

Answer (score 0):

With your use of setattr `setattr(some_instance, 'string_type', some_instance.text_type)` you you have actually made instance property named string_type property actually point to the text_type property.  So two names one property

```
The db, ndb, users, urlfetch, and memcache modules are imported.
> from google.appengine.ext import db
> class TestModel(db.Model):
...    string_type = db.StringProperty(default='', multiline=True)
...    text_type = db.TextProperty()
... 
> 
> some_instance = TestModel()
> some_instance.text_type = 'foobar'
> setattr(some_instance, 'string_type', some_instance.text_type)
> print type(some_instance.string_type)
<class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Text'>
y> repr(some_instance.string_type)
"u'foobar'"
> id(some_instance.string_type)
168217452
> id(some_instance.text_type)
168217452
> some_instance.string_type.__class__
<class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Text'>
> some_instance.text_type.__class__
<class 'google.appengine.api.datastore_types.Text'>
> dir(some_instance.text_type.__class__)
```

Note the id of the two properties above.

So you are effectively rebinding the instance level property definition, then this modified model is written with the type of the field to the datastore.

If you want to use setattr (though can't see why in this contrived example) you should be getting the value from the property first using `setattr(some_instance.string_type,TestModel.string_type.get_value_for_datastore(some_instance)
)` to get the value to be assigned and not rebind the instances property.

Comment: Your example only works because you don't `put` and then `get` the entity from datastore. If you add this to your example (as per my modified answer), the `id`s of `string_type` and `text_type` will be unique

Comment: The property will be unique after the get because you have created a new instance of TextProperty, which has nothing to do with the problem you have created for yourself.  What I am trying to explain is when you do the setattr in your example you are just binding the `string_type` to the same property instance.  When you retrieve each instance of the property from the datastore you are getting two copies each unique.  You should spend a little time getting your head around name binding in python, which explains what is going on.